# How to change the resolution of a layer on IOS 5

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing a opengl es 2.0 app on ios 5. I paint a texture as background. When I rotate the device, I need to rotate the layer and change the dimensions of the layer.
The problem is that I can change the bounds of the layer, but the layer resolution is the same.
I mean, if I have a layer with the bounds 1024*768 and I define the new layers bounds as 768*1024, the layers size changes, but when I paint a 768*1024 texture as background, the image is deformed.

I use the functions `canvasView.bounds = newCanvasRect;` and `canvasView.frame = newCanvasRect;` to change the layers size (where canvasView is the layer and newCanvasRect the new boundaries).

Any ideas?

Comment: You should change projection matrix

Comment: First of all, thank you for the idea, but if I change the projection matrix, I only change the scene, but the scene is properly. The problem becomes when I change the viewport, because if I define the layer with the dimensions of the canvas when is in portrait, it looks good in portrait, and if I define the dimensions in landscape, it looks good in landscape.

Comment: I every time change projection matrix

`float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
_projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(25.0f), aspect, NEAR_PLANE, DEFAULT_TRANSLATE_Z*FAR_PLANE);`

Comment: Ok, you were right. Adapting the perspective I can adapt teh content using the same viewport. Thank you very much again. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to destroy and rebuild your frame buffer each time the device rotates for the new height and width.  Use layoutsubviews to trigger all of this, which gets called when the orientation changes:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
   NSLog(@"layoutSubviews");
   [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];
   [self destroyFramebuffer];
   [self createFramebuffer];
}


- (void)destroyFramebuffer {
   NSLog(@"destroy buffer");

   glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
   viewFramebuffer = 0;
   glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
   viewRenderbuffer = 0;
   glDeleteRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
   depthRenderbuffer = 0;
}


- (BOOL)createFramebuffer {
   NSLog(@"creating buffer");

   glGenFramebuffers(1, &viewFramebuffer);
   glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, viewFramebuffer);

   glGenRenderbuffers(1, &viewRenderbuffer);
   glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

   // setup the renderbuffer to the context
   [[EAGLContext currentContext] renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:(CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer];
   glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, viewRenderbuffer);

   // Allocate color buffer backing based on the current layer size (get the current layer size)
   glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_WIDTH, &backingWidth);
   glGetRenderbufferParameteriv(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RENDERBUFFER_HEIGHT, &backingHeight);

   NSLog(@"backing width: %d height: %d",backingWidth, backingHeight);

   // set up the depth buffer
   glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthRenderbuffer);
   glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
   glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, backingWidth, backingHeight);
   glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthRenderbuffer);
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

   [self setupView];

   return YES;
}
```

Then use backingWidth and backingHeight to recreate your projection matrix.

Comment: Man.. I hate answering a question and then realizing that it was a year old.  Sucks that stackoverflow isn't better about putting old stale questions in search results.